# Is is safe to "Enroll all Factory Default keys" in BIOS?

Tags: bios

To enable Secure Boot, I've found that enrolling all factory default keys could potentially fix a problem I'm facing where it says it's in Setup Mode.
But what are the consequences of that... Will I loose any data? Will my OS (Windows 11) be wiped?

Comment: Do you mean default keys (I have not heard of this) or default settings?  I never harmed any system by restoring BIOS (UEFI) to default.

Comment: potential duplicates [What does "factory default" mean regarding UEFI keys stored in a TPM, in a PC built from scratch?](https://superuser.com/questions/1605318) and [What is the difference between Provision Factory Default Keys and Enroll all Factory Default Keys in UEFI?](https://superuser.com/questions/1419393). Also see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/358185/secure-boot-key-management.html

Comment: It's impossible to lose data by just enabling Secure Boot.